# LoggingSession.SaveToFileAsync() fails with "Access denied"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I write to a `StorageFolder` to make sure I do have access to it, and in the next line I try to save a  `LoggingSession` but it fails because "access is denied".

Session creation:

```
var channel = new LoggingChannel("Channel1", new LoggingChannelOptions());
var session = new LoggingSession("Session1");
session.AddLoggingChannel(channel, LoggingLevel.Warning);
channel.LogMessage("Test message", LoggingLevel.Error);
```

Writing:

```
//"folder" is a StorageFolder that as we can see, I do have permission to write to.
StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("test"); 
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("t1.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "abc");
var testFile = await session.SaveToFileAsync(folder, "testlog.txt");//access denied
```

So why does the `LoggingSession` get an access denied?

Comment: what is the path of `folder` at the time of calling the `await session.SaveToFileAsync(` method..?

Comment: It is the expected path. The path that the app just created a file in, and wrote to it (1 line before).

Comment: Unable to repro using `IStorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`. Do you have a complete repro?

Comment: @MattLacey Thanks. Your way worked. So now I don't understand - Why would a folder that I _do_ have permission to - fail? Perhaps LoggingSession has a more stringent access limit.

Comment: @ispiro do you have an example of a folder which will recreate the problem you saw?

Comment: @MattLacey Yes. for example: `StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("test");` . Edited into question now.